# how to remove an entry from hashmap by checking its value?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, iteration

I have a java map with string in its key and integer in its value. I want to remove a particular entry(key/value) from this map which doesn't have value greater than 5. Can any body suggest me how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've only got a regular map (i.e. no additional data structure that implements a reverse mapping), then your best option is to iterate the value set, test each value, and use `Iterator.remove()` to remove the relevant ones.

If you have a secondary data structure, you may be able to use it to identify the entries to be removed.  But the "cost" is that such a data structure takes space to represent and time to update ... and your code is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I did the job as following. Thanks to Stephen C:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> iter = TestMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = iter.next();
    if(entry.getValue() <= 5){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```